# Titanium: Android Build Tools are too new and may or may not work with Titanium issue

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

When I do a build on Android I get the following warning on the console:

```
[WARN] :   
[WARN] :   Android Build Tools 25.0.2 are too new and may or may not work with Titanium.
[WARN] :   If you encounter problems, select a supported version with:
[WARN] :      ti config android.buildTools.selectedVersion ##.##.##
[WARN] :    where ##.##.## is a version in  that is 23.x
3/16/2017, 6:06:56 PM
Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Home
  Version                     = 10.0.14393
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 17107111936
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 6.9.4
  npm Version                 = 3.10.10
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.11
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 6.0.1.GA
  SDK Path                    = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.1.GA
  Target Platform             = android
Command
```

However, I have now installed build tool v23.0.3 and restarted appcelerator but the warning still appears.

How do I make this warning message go away?

Answer (score 3):

For my experience if you develop mobile with more than one instrument (Titanium, Android, Xamarin, ...) it's always better to download more separated android-sdk directories. If you followed this caution, just go inside your build-tools folder of the sdk used by Titanium and remove all the folders of versions higher than 23.0.x.

Mine is in: `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Titanium/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools`

Comment: Interesting. I have set up the SDK on Android Studio. Will this be an issue? Also if I wanted to switch using your method, how can I do it? Is it also possible without re-downloading all over again as it takes sooo long to download.

Comment: I warmly suggest you to keep separated the two sdk folders. It's better if you change the directory used by Titanium downloading, from inside Appcelerator Studio (or with the CLI), only the sdk you need (the last one you can use). I did your mistake once.

Comment: Yeah I think your right. How would I go about changing directories and re-downloading all the SDK's. Can a simple copy and paste do. Also what about the SDK manager. Wouldn't that still download to Android Studio? I still want Android Studio to work as expected!

Comment: No no, don't copy anything from Android Studio.
From Appcelerator Studio: preferences => Studio => Platforms => Android, change the directory, close anything, re-open, some blasphemies, install only the SDKs you need from inside Appcelerator Studio. If you get in trouble work try to use `appc setup`. Good luck.

Comment: So how would I actually install the SDKs. The SDK manager automatically downloads everything to here: `C:\Users\yahya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`. When I meant copy and pasting, I meant copy the SDK's from there and put it in the directory you mentioned. If I don't do the copy and paste approach, how should I install it?

Comment: IMHO it's better if you create a empty folder, you set it as Android sdk folder on Appc Studio and you restart everything downloading everything again. It's a slower approach but you are sure that your file will be exactly how Titanium need them and after you don't risk strange bugs (with Proguard for instance). Up to you, there are plenty of guides online.

Comment: Ok I understand I should download everything again, but how? I normally use the SDK manager, but that downloads it to `C:\Users\yahya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Comment: In preferences => Studio => Platforms => Android there is a button to download the SDKs you need, without using sdk manager.